# How can I create a React front end that allows me to deploy a Solidity contract?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I am able to build the interface for the React app. I am able to create a deploy script using "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers" that compiles a .sol contract and successfully deploys it. What I cannot do is combine the two.

What I want is to click a button in the React app to deploy the contract.

I want to use hardhat's ethers.getContractFactory() method to compile and then deploy.

When I add "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers" to my project with

```
const { ethers } = require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
```

I get an error about Hardhat context being required, so i add

```
require('hardhat').config()
```

Then I get

```
"Module not found: can't resolve 'async_hooks' in /node_modules/undici/lib/api"
```

Is there another library I can use to achieve what I want, or am I just missing something/doing something wrong?

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(process.env.REACT_APP_ALCHEMY_KEY);
require('hardhat').config();
const { ethers } = require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

export const deployAuction = async (options) => {

  const AuctionFactory = new ethers.getContractFactory("Auction");

  // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
  const auction = await AuctionFactory.deploy(
   options.token,
   options.paymentToken,
   options.bidIncrement,
   options.timeoutPeriod
   );   
  console.log("Contract deployed to address:", auction.address);

  return auction.address;
};
```

Please, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you deployed the contract with hardhat, you will see `artifacts` folder which stores the deployed contracts. since your contract name is `Auction` you will have `artifacts/contracts/Auction/Auction.json`. this JSON files includes the abi code of your contract. to create a contract instance you need to bring it to your frond-end.

To create a contract instance you need 3 arguments:

1- Address of the contract

2- abi of the contract

3- provider

```
// I wrapped with function to be able to use "await"
const createContract = async () => {
  // make sure you pass correct path
  // fetching json works in next.js, I believe React18 supprts it
  const res = await fetch('artifacts/contracts/Auction/Auction.json');
  const artifact = await res.json();
  // address is inisde the json file. 5 is goeerli.
  // depending on your config, you might have a different networkId
  const address = artifact.networks[5].address;
  // in react.js window.ethereum will be defined. in next.js you need to add if(window.ethereum){code here}
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

  const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, artifact.abi, provider);
  return contract;
};
```

Comment: Address is not in the json. I only see _format, contractName, sourceName, abi, byteCode, deployedByteCode, linkReferences, and deployedLinkReferences